# Gravity form gform_validation filter not working

Tags: php, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to post data to third party API and depending upon the response I need to cancel form submission. But I'm still getting form entries in gravity form backend.

Here is my code:

```
add_filter('gform_validation_10', 'stop_form_submission_validation');
function stop_form_submission_validation($validation_result){
    $form = $validation_result['form'];

    foreach ( $form['fields'] as $field ) {

        //NOTE: replace 1 with the field you would like to validate
        if ( $field->id == 1 ) {
            // set the form validation to false
            $validation_result["is_valid"] = false;
            $field->failed_validation  = true;
            $field->validation_message = 'This field is invalid!';
            break;
        }
    }
    $validation_result['form'] = $form;
    return $validation_result;
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, i found a solution [here](https://gravityplus.pro/how-to/prevent-gravity-forms-entry-creation/)

```html
GFAPI::delete_entry( $entry['id'] );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the array value by reference. Otherwise you're modifying a copy of the array item, not the item itself.

Change this:

```
    foreach ( $form['fields'] as $field ) {
```

To this:

```
    foreach ( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
```

Comment: Does your form have id 10?